# rails 4 - Boostrap 3 , having hard time in getting right with specific fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, fonts, asset-pipeline

I am trying to use some specific font  ( Open Sans ) and I always get an error on my first page load ( not on the reload..) :

```
     Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-22 18:31:45 +0200
      ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
    Processing by HighVoltage::PagesController#show as HTML
      Parameters: {"id"=>"home"}
      Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (177.8ms)
      Rendered layouts/application/_footer.html.erb (9.4ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 4609ms (Views: 4594.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


    Started GET "/fonts/opensans/Light/OpenSans-Light.woff" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-22 18:31:52 +0200
    ------
    # then on reload

    Started GET "/" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-08-22 18:36:32 +0200
    Processing by HighVoltage::PagesController#show as HTML
      Parameters: {"id"=>"home"}
      Rendered pages/home.html.erb within layouts/application (2.6ms)
      Rendered layouts/application/_footer.html.erb (3.8ms)
    Completed 200 OK in 270ms (Views: 269.0ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

I have these fonts in my assets

```
 app/assets/fonts/opensans/Bold
 app/assets/fonts/opensans/BoldItalic
 app/assets/fonts/opensans/EXtraBold...
```

In  config/application.rb , I added

config.assets.paths << Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "fonts") 
    config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif *.svg *.ico *.eot *.ttf)

In my style.css.scss , I have

```
    /*------------------------------------------------------------------
    [5. Form Elements]
    */
    /* Open Sans @font-face kit */
    /* BEGIN Light */
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Open Sans';
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: 300;
      src: local('OpenSans-Light'), 
      url('../fonts/opensans/Light/OpenSans-Light.eot'),
      url('../fonts/opensans/Light/OpenSans-Light.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
      url('../fonts/opensans/Light/OpenSans-Light.woff') format('woff'), 
      url('../fonts/opensans/Light/OpenSans-Light.ttf') format('truetype'), 
      url('../fonts/opensans/Light/OpenSans-Light.svg#OpenSansLight') format('svg');
    }
    /* END Light */
```

what could be wrong in my settings ?
thanks for enlightments

Answer (score 0):

too bad .. I only need to change all

```
url('../fonts/opensans
```

to

```
font-url('opensans
```

in my scss file
which will generate url(/assets/opensans...  to get my fonts !